# finding the load?

Tags: linux

I am currently using a linux system (linaro) which has a 2.4ghz and 5ghz msata cards plugged into the 1.2ghz 1gb ram board.

this board also has a web application on it (so people can connect to it like a router and use it as a server also)

here is my question:

The web page takes longer than they should to load. (around 4 seconds)

I have spent time optimizing the web an gotten response time down to 2ish seconds but this is still to slow for a web application. I want to know what is the best way on the linux system to find the fail point? I want to monitor my system and see if the wireless is struggling (bandwidth), the processing , the mysql database, the PHP, the ram? what is the best way to find answers?

I can fix and optimize what ever issue there is, but i need to find the bottle neck first..

Comment: Regarding the "on hold": seems to me like a legit question. Most users only know `top`. But it is of little use for web use cases because `top` has no info about I/O (which is responsible for most bottlenecks) and it's uncomfortable to use.

Comment: @Philip I thought it was a well formed question :( nothing broad about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to debug the problem on the Linux system, you can get a high-level overview with these tools in real-time:

- `htop` to get an overview of CPU and memory usage
- `iotop` to see general I/O throughput (must be run as root - "`sudo`")
- `nethogs` to see network I/O in detail (also root)

Some other commands are helpful, but are not real-time:

- `netstat` (I prefer `sudo netstat -tunap`) shows you UDP and TCP connections and their connection state
- `ls -l /proc/123/fd` shows open file descriptors of process # 123 (fd's are used for all kinds of I/O)

Regarding mysql you should also consider running a vacuum from time to time and also analyze what indexes you use where. More over you should be aware that `JOIN`s or subsequent `SELECT`s can easily become a bottle-neck.

I must add that the above toolset is quite low-level. When profiling/optimizing a web app, I usually prefer to use more high-level tools that are actually OS-independent. Log files help a lot and you should consider using `print` to log timestamps. This way you get an idea which part of the function takes how long to execute. Usually I/O operations are the slowest things.

Also I really recommend using [Webpagetest.org](http://webpagetest.org), it gives you nice waterfall charts of all the HTTP requests that go from the Browser.

Comment: thanks I will use these on monday and write a comment, I use chrome tools to see the response, I can see the bottle neck is the from the server not the front end (e.g. pictures taking a long time along with other things) ... but I need to prove or disprove that its the networking, so i can provide an argument to switch from mysql to a hybrid of maria db and noSQL